# Is there any specification to describe the functionality of KafkaAvroSerializer / KafkaAvroDeserializer or the confluent platform registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am wondering whether the confluent schema-registry paradigm (which to my understanding is paired with `KafkaAvroSerializer`/`KafkaAvroDeserializer` implementation) changes over time. If it does, is it based on some publicly available specification?

I consider that I should somehow be able to know what types of requests (GET/POST/PUT e.t.c.) the `KafkaAvroSerializer` and `KafkaAvroDeserializer`  are supposed to perform to the confluent-schema registry and how it is decided whether a schema will be added to the registry or not.

Also in the second diagram below I see that kafka communicates  with the schema-registry for validating
the schema. But every answer I have seen till now is that kafka does not know anything about schemas.

Is this a recent change? Is depicted to a change-log intended for maintainers of project using confluent registry?

From page: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/6.2/schema-registry/index.html

[image: schema-registry-and-kafka-6.2]

From page: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.5/schema-registry/index.html
[image: schema-registry-ecosystem-7.5]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it changes.

For example, around 4.x release, they added SubjectNameStrategy so that multiple schemas could be stored per topic.

There's also an Avro upgrade from 1.8 to 1.10, I think somewhere in between 5.x and 7.x

The Schema Registry server itself has had some additional endpoints added, as well over several releases, but they've all been backward compatible.

Ultimately, Confluent has a whole page dedicated to release notes that you can checkout

It's correct that Kafka doesn't know about schemas. That doesn't mean schemas (or ids / lookup keys) cannot be encoded as bytes, then used in Kafka

> should somehow be able to know what types of requests

The project is open source. Otherwise, TCP Dump and Wireshark would help